# How can I certificate my Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, https, certificate

I'm new about Android programming. I wrote a login (username and password), and after the user writes these things I start a new https url intent. 
Where I have to certificate, and again write the user and password. 
So I'd like to write a code, that asks fot the user and password just once, and later he/she don't need to write it again...
I tried this:

```
String URL = "Myurl";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(URL));
i.putExtra(userName, userName);
i.putExtra(password, password);
startActivity(i);
```

Could someone help about it?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do.
You want to save user password and login somewhere on server and than access it later?

Comment: user write username and password then start intent where a browser intent (https) and have to certificate again with the username and password, but there don write again the username and password just once in the login screen in the beginning and later dont write again

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure that i understand you correctly, but.
You can save info about username and password in SharedPreferences.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: I think you'll want to look into setting up SSH authentication for your app. Essentially it's what you want, authenticate once, create a key identifying the device as valid then the next time you won't need to log in as long as you have a valid key.